# Is there a way to get NSPanel “Non activating” style functionality on an NSWindow?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nswindow

`NSPanel` has a “Non activating” option for HUD Panels. I’d like to get that same functionality working on an `NSWindow`, i.e. I want the window to accept clicks but not take focus away from whatever the active app is (by this I mean the app that was active before clicking on the window activated my app—in this case Sketch).

I have tried creating an `NSWindow` subclass and setting `canBecomeMainWindow` and `canBecomeKeyWindow` to `NO` but that doesn’t seem to be working—I think because those settings only apply to windows *within the same app*.

What I’m trying to do here is prevent [this flickering](https://images.typed.com/e4d48a0f-79a6-4a96-bf4d-9535d4a0f889/_tools.gif). I’m pretty sure this is doable as apps like Alfred seem to be doing it.

Comment: Hi Elliot and welcome to SO. When you ask a question try to insert snippets of code to demonstrate what you have done and where your problem lies. That will attract more users to study your question in detail and provide you with an answer.

Comment: Why not use an `NSPanel`? It **is** a window. Anything you can do with an `NSWindow`, you can also do with an `NSPanel`. There are a few methods/properties which change their default behavior, but you can use overrides to change those back.

Comment: @KenThomases Thanks for the reply Ken. The problems I ran into with NSPanel were making the whole window light rather than dark and trying to set `NSWindowTitleHidden`. In my `NSWindow` I have these appearance settings and then a `NSVisualEffectView` set to light: `self.window.styleMask = self.window.styleMask | NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask; self.window.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleHidden; self.window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = YES;`

Comment: I haven't tested, but I expect it should work if you set the panel's `appearance` property (which it has by virtue of conforming to the `NSAppearanceCustomization` protocol) to `[NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameVibrantLight]`.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this @KenThomases, in the end I managed to get to go light by adding a `NSVisualEffectView` set to light to the view controller. I tried `[NSAppearance appearanceNamed:NSAppearanceNameVibrantLight]` too but couldn’t get it. Thanks again!